# Having considered . . . into account

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Is the structure of the bold phrase in the following expression grammatically right?

> *In conclusion, **having considered the aforementioned reasons and examples into account**, I do believe that ... .*

If it is right, what structure does " **having considered ... Into account**" follow?

If it is not true, what can be a perfect alternative for that?

Comment: The correct phrase is: **having taken ...into account**. (The use of **aforementioned** is very formal!)

Comment: @Ronald Sole , Thanks for the response. What is the problem of using "considered"?

Comment: Incidentally, the _having_ clause is a supplementary adjunct. It doesn't modify anything but simply provides additional non-integrated content.

Comment: It should be "having **taken** the aforementioned reasons and examples into account ...", or simply "having considered the aforementioned reasons and examples ..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two different adverbial expressions (with much the same meaning) being mashed together in OP's example...

> 1: ***Having considered** the aforementioned reasons and examples, I think...*
> 2: ***Having taken** the aforementioned reasons and examples **into account**, I think...*

Use one or the other (whichever appeals to you), not both.

Comment: "Use one or the other (whichever appeals to you), not both." Using both can be fine. "Having considered and taken into account the aforementioned reasons and examples, I think..."

Comment: I suppose you're right (there *are* half-a-dozen written instances of ["Having considered and taken into account"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Having+considered+and+taken+into+account%22) in Google Books). But even though I don't object to tautology in general, it seems a bit clunky in this particular case. And it's not an "established (legal) collocation" like ***aid and abet*** or ***cease and desist***, so I still think it would be best for most native speakers and practically *all* non-native speakers to stick with the advice in the final sentence of my answer.

Comment: I suppose "having considered and taken into account" would contrast with "having considered and chosen to ignore", but that is not what the OP was about.